# ECMAScript algorithm for Function.prototype.call.call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

It is well known that `Function.prototype.call.call(func)` is the same as `Function.call.call(func)` which is the same as `func()`

This technique has been working since the first browsers. Hence the algorithm for "double call" can be easily derived, say, from [ES5 specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4)

> **Function.prototype.call (thisArg [ , arg1 [ , arg2, … ] ] )**
> When the *call* method is called on an object *func* with argument *thisArg* and optional arguments *arg1, arg2* etc, the following steps are taken:
>
> > 1. If *IsCallable*(*func*) is false, then throw a *TypeError* exception.
> > 2. Let *argList* be an empty *List*.
> > 3. If this method was called with more than one argument then in left to right order starting with *arg1* append each argument as the last element of *argList*
> > 4. Return the result of calling the *[[Call]]* internal method of *func*, providing *thisArg* as the *this* value and *argList* as the list of arguments.

Consider a simple example:

```js
var func = function(){ console.log(42) };
Function.prototype.call.call(func);
```

So `.call.call(func)` is a call of internal method [[Call]] of `Function.prototype.call` providing `func` as *this* value. How come this leads to the call of `func`?

Looks like [[Call]] internal method of `.call` actually calls its *this* value (as in case of `func.call()`). But I didn't get it from the spec.

Comment: If you are not overly obsessed with the ES5 spec, maybe the [contemporary spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.call) will be more direct in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`[[Call]]` is an internal method of all function objects. It performs the actual function call by setting up the context and evaluating the body of the function.

From the [ES5 Specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/):

> #### [13.2.1 `[[Call]]`](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-13.2.1)
>
> When the `[[Call]]` internal method for a Function object *F* is called with a this value and a list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *funcCtx* be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of *F*'s `[[FormalParameters]]` internal property, the passed arguments List args, and the **this** value as described in 10.4.3.
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the *FunctionBody* that is the value of *F*'s `[[Code]]` internal property. If *F* does not have
>    a `[[Code]]` internal property or if its value is an empty
>    FunctionBody, then *result* is *(normal, undefined, empty)*.
> 3. Exit the execution context *funcCtx*, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If *result*.type is throw then throw *result*.value.
> 5. If *result*.type is return then return *result*.value.
> 6. Otherwise *result*.type must be normal. Return **undefined**.

---

However, do note that `[[Call]]` is also used by the `fn()` function call syntax (look at step 8):

> #### [11.2.3 Function Calls](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.2.3)
>
> The production  *CallExpression*  :  *MemberExpression*  *Arguments*  is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let  *ref*  be the result of evaluating  *MemberExpression*.
> 2. Let  *func*  be  GetValue(*ref*).
> 3. Let  *argList*  be the result of evaluating  *Arguments*, producing an internal list of argument values (see 11.2.4).
> 4. If  Type(*func*) is not Object, throw a  **TypeError**  exception.
> 5. If  IsCallable is  **false**, throw a  **TypeError**  exception.
> 6. If  Type(*ref*) is  Reference, then
>
>    1. If  IsPropertyReference(*ref*) is  **true**, then
>
>       1. Let  *thisValue*  be  GetBase(*ref*).
>    2. Else, the base of  *ref*  is an  Environment Record
>
>       1. Let  *thisValue*  be the result of calling the ImplicitThisValue concrete method of  GetBase(*ref*).
> 7. Else,  Type(*ref*) is not  Reference.
>
>    1. Let  *thisValue*  be  **undefined**.
> 8. Return the result of calling the **`[[Call]]`** internal method on  *func*, providing  *thisValue*  as the  **this**  value and providing the list  *argList*  as the argument values.
>
> The production  *CallExpression*  :  *CallExpression*  *Arguments*  is
> evaluated in exactly the same manner, except that the contained
> *CallExpression*  is evaluated in step 1.

Comment: Ok, 13.2.1 says: **Let result be the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]]**. So `.call1.call2(func)` is suppose to evaluate `.call1` FunctionBody, but it does evaluate the `func` body which is _this_ value.

Comment: It is either a spec flaw or invisible magic hidden in the depths of the ECMAScript text.

Comment: @raiseman: It could very well be that this behavior was underspecified (or implied) in the ES5 spec, but the new versions distinguish between user defined functions and built-in functions (`Function.prototype.call` is a built-in function). The latter have a different `[[Call]]` implementation: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist